# JavaScript Add to Bookmark not working in FF >= 23.0

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cross-browser, bookmarks

My JavaScript code to bookmark search, which works fine for Chrome, IE and FF versions less than 23.0, but not for versions greater than 23.0. Can anybody help me with this? 
I also read http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/23.0beta/releasenotes/ for the changes in Firefox versions > 23.0.
Current Code:

```
function bookmarkUrl(title, url){
    if ( window.sidebar ) window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, '');
}
function bookmarkTip(tiptext){
    document.getElementById('bookmark_tip').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('bookmark_tip_text').innerHTML = tiptext;
}   
function firefox_bookmark(title, url) {
    jQuery('#bookmark_tip').show();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('#bookmark_tip').fadeOut(500); 
    }, 30000);
    bookmarkUrl(title, url);
}
```

HTML:
`<a class="bookmark" onclick="firefox_bookmark('cricket', 'url');">Bookmark this link</a>`

Comment: can you add the code to your question, so we can help you ?

Comment: The error is, because FF 23.0 has dropped the (window.side.addPanel) funtion 
bug 691647 ( https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691647).
for further read this, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23

Answer (score 0):

As @poonamThaPar states, Firefox have removed the proprietary function `window.sidebar.addPanel` from Firefox v23 ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23#DOM), third bullet point)

Line 4 of your (formatted) script block below is the offending line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bookmarkUrl(title, url){ 
    if (window.sidebar)
      window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, ""); // <-- Function removed in Firefox v23
  }
  function bookmarkTip(tiptext){
    document.getElementById('bookmark_tip').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('bookmark_tip_text').innerHTML = tiptext;
  }
  function firefox_bookmark(title, url) {
    jQuery("#bookmark_tip").show(); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
      jQuery("#bookmark_tip").fadeOut(500); 
    }, 30000);
    bookmarkUrl(title, url);
  }
</script>
<a class="bookmark" onclick="firefox_bookmark('cricket', 'url');">Bookmark this link</a>
```

Comment: Just realised @poonamThaPar was also the person that asked the question *facepalm*